# Trabalhar com funções pesadas / demoradas em react (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, react, rsa

Tenho um projeto React em que quando o usuário abre uma página, o aplicativo começa a criar um par de chaves 2048 RSA. Como faço para garantir que a página não "trave", ou seja, ela fica em segundo plano e quando a chave é criada informo ao usuário que está tudo pronto.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
        const [keyStatus, setKeyStatus] = useState('Em processamento... (É normal que a pagina parece ter crashado! Por favor espere!)');
        const [pubKey, setPubKey] = useState('');
        const [privKey, setPrivKey] = useState('');
        const [genState, setGenState] = useState(0);
        function exitModal(){
            modal.setModal(true);
        }
        async function downloadPrivKey() {
            if(genState === 1){
                await api.post('/savePublicKey', {
                    publicKey: pubKey
                }).then(function(response){
                    fileDownload(privKey, 'private.key', 'text/plain');
                    setGenState(2);
                }).catch(function (){
                    navigate('/', { replace: true });
                });
            }
        }
        useEffect(() => {
      async function startGenerationKeys() {
        const keysWorker = new Worker();
        keysWorker.postMessage("start");
        keysWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
            setPrivKey(e.data.privKey);
            setPubKey(e.data.pubKey);
            setKeyStatus('Pronta para download!');
            setGenState(1);
        };
    }
    startGenerationKeys();
        }, []);
```

WebWorker:

```
    import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';

    export default onmessage = function() {
        const keysPair = new NodeRSA({ b: 4096 });
        const pubKey = keysPair.exportKey('public').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        const privKey = keysPair.exportKey('private');
        postMessage({
            pubKey,
            privKey
        });
    }
```

Comment: `await new NodeRSA({ b: 4096 });`  isso aqui não faz sentido. Construtores não são _async_.

Comment: Web Workers poderia ser uma saída, delegando a tarefa para uma thread separada. Dê uma pesquisada nessa direção.

Comment: Tentei colocar um webWorker. a página continua a travar, inclusive aparece um aviso de "Página sem resposta" do Google Chrome.